# Installation of node-red contrib nodes

Tags: raspbian, nodered

I installed node-red, and I tried installing the contrib nodes from `flows.nodered`. It is getting installed, but in the browser, I can't find the nodes which I have installed. I used the same procedure for installation on my desktop, where I got my nodes properly.

I have attached the screen shot here:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If you don't get a follow-up with any better suggestions, you might want to create an issue on the GitHub issues page for the core project found here:

https://github.com/monteslu/node-red-contrib-meshblu

Comment: Install it externally of Node-RED will not change palette in browser. You need to go right sandwich menu / manage palette / install

Answer (score 0):

Install it externally of Node-RED will not change palette in browser. You need to go right sandwich menu / manage palette / install